# JFrame duplicates drawings when resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, out-of-memory

I wrote a code in Java (using swing) which draws few polygons on a panel.

```
public MyClass extends JPanel
```

The code is very simple (but long) and basically adds few Polygons, then adds few points to each polygon and then draw them on the screen (with `drawPolygon`).

My problem is when I run the program, I can't see the drawings on the panel. 
After a while, I figure out that when I re-size my frame, I can suddenly see the drawing but it duplicates itself many times (depends how much I re-size). If I play enough time with the resizing, I get:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Also, `myPolygon.invalidate()` doesn't help.

When using `setResizable(false)` I can't see my drawing at all.

Does anyone have a solution?

Duplicate Image Screenshot:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3BgZ.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can we see more code? Have u included the super.paint(g) line?

Comment: Can you please be more careful when making edits to the question?  Twice now you have wiped out edits made by other people!

Comment: @imulsion yes I did.
Since I don't have enough space to write here my code here is a link:
[link](http://pastie.org/4758054)
Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry about that.

Comment: OK - I have made another edit.  Tips.  1) Make sure to check the preview below the posting form before posting. 2) Don't edit a question by hitting the 'back button' - instead use the llink below the post. 3) The '4 spaces prefix' for code formatting only works if there is an entirely blank line before the code block.  4) Code, code snippets, proper class names & I/O should all use code formatting. 5) Code formatting 'in-line' is achieved by wrapping the text in ` 6) To avoid peppering the entire text with things like '`JPanel`', use the more generic 'panel'.  Just tag as Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, in your `paintComponent` method, don't call

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
setVisible(true);
validate();
```

This will request a repaint, cause `paintComponent` to be recalled and you'll end up in a nasty loop, consuming your CPU and (as you have found out), your memory.

IF you can get away with it, you're better off to draw the polygon to a buffer and draw the buffer to the screen on each iteration of the `paintComponent`.  This will be faster in the long run...

```
// Create a field
private BufferedImage buffer;

// Call this when you need to change the polygon some how...
protected void createBuffer() {

    // You need to determine the width and height values ;)
    buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

    int xoffset=5;//Multiply in order to "zoom" the picture
    int offset=0;//moves shape to the right

    p.addPoint(40*xoffset-offset, 30*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(50*xoffset-offset,30*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(57*xoffset-offset,37*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(57*xoffset-offset,47*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(50*xoffset-offset,54*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(40*xoffset-offset,54*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(33*xoffset-offset,47*xoffset-offset);
    p.addPoint(33*xoffset-offset, 37*xoffset-offset);

    g.drawPolygon(p);
    g.dispose();

}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (buffer != null) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawImage(buffer, translateX, translateY, this);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So, anyway, the other fun things you're doing are...

1. Creating a static reference to your Polygon.  Hope you weren't intending to have more the one on the screen at a time ;)
2. Add new points to an already existing polygon (each time `paintComponent` was called)
3. Translating the polygon each time `paintComponent` was called

Try something like this instead

```
public class RoundTop extends JPanel {

    //Polygons declarations
    private Polygon p = new Polygon();
    //Translate variables;
    private int translateX = 10;
    private int translateY = 10;

    public RoundTop() {

        int xoffset = 5;//Multiply in order to "zoom" the picture
        int offset = 0;//moves shape to the right

        p.addPoint(40 * xoffset - offset, 30 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(50 * xoffset - offset, 30 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(57 * xoffset - offset, 37 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(57 * xoffset - offset, 47 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(50 * xoffset - offset, 54 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(40 * xoffset - offset, 54 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(33 * xoffset - offset, 47 * xoffset - offset);
        p.addPoint(33 * xoffset - offset, 37 * xoffset - offset);

        p.translate(translateX, translateY);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2d.drawPolygon(p);

        g2d.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, 
I erased those lines but still doesn't work.

Comment: The reason I used Polygon is that I need to know if a user clicks inside a polygon, a thing that AFAIK I can't do with BufferedImage (The shapes are not squares or rectangles).